# Mac OS X architecture and command line

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix, programming-languages

I study Computer Science at University. They use **Ubuntu** to teach about **Unix** architecture, so they speak about *processes* (father/son), *forks*, *pipes*, *threads*, *scheduling* and so on. I want to buy a new notebook, and I was thinking about Mac OS X. My questions are about this field:

- what is Mac OS X architecture?
- can you use Unix commands (fork, pipe, ...)?
- what are the differences between Linux OSs and Mac OS X relating to this field?
- can I write in C language in Mac OS X directly using the command line and the `gcc` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is Mac OS X architecture?

Mac OS X uses [Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)), a modified [Mach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_(kernel)) hybrid kernel with a FreeBSD-like system call interface. Modern Apple computers use ARM (AArch64) or x86 (x86_64/amd64) processors, but earlier versions of OS X also ran on PowerPC platforms like earlier Power Macs.

> can you use Unix commands (fork, pipe, ...)?

Mac OS X is IEEE 1003.1 (POSIX) certified. You can use both POSIX library functions like `fork`, `pipe`, `open`, `read`, and `write`, and POSIX command line utilities like `ls`, `sh`, `cd`, `mkdir`, and `ed`.

POSIX is the industry standard for operating systems which contains large parts of the UNIX API and is implemented by all major operating system vendors including Microsoft (they purposefully botched their POSIX implementation to be useless though).

> what are the differences between Linux OSs and Mac OS X relating to this field?

Both Linux and Mac OS X are UNIX-like operating systems. Both have considerable differences to a “proper” UNIX like Solaris or OpenBSD, yet they still feel pretty similar when programming non-GUI software for them, the GUI system is completely different in the two (Linux typically uses the X windowing system, on OS X you would use Cocoa, although X is available, too).

> can I write in C language in Mac OS X directly using the command line and the gcc command?

Yes. The default compiler on OS X is `clang` with `gcc` being available, too, if I remember correctly. On all POSIX platforms, you can always portably invoke a C compiler with the `cc`, `c89`, or `c99` commands.